# confusion in vector triple product

Tags: vectors

I am confuse that if we are two vector triple product for example [a b c] and [x y z] and given that both are equal . Where a,b,c,x,y,z are vectors . Then can we say that a=x , b=y ,c=z ?

Comment: No we cannot. $[a b c] = [b c a]$. But in general when $a, b, c$ are distinct, $a \neq b$.

Comment: @taninamdar how this relates to my question.

Comment: $[a b c]$ and $[b c a]$ are two equal vector triple products, even though they involve same set of $3$ vectors. But the vectors in question are not equal.

Comment: @taninamdar Thank you